# getting nil value while decoding the data

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

The response of the api.

```
["data": {
email = "sm@bl.com";
firstName = ll;
lastName = "mm!";
role = user;
token = "Bearer xxxxxxxxx";
}, "status": 200, "message": Record Sucessfully Inserted.]
```

Based on the response I have created the structs are

```
struct NewUser: Codable {
var message: String?
var data: NewUserData?
var status: Int?
```

}

```
struct  NewUserData: Codable {
var email: String?
var firstName: Int?
var lastName: String?
var role: String?
var token: String?
}
```

If I am not using the JSONDecoder is working file like in below code

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            print(json)
```

it's working fine but as I try to follow the JSONDecoder

```
let jsondecode = JSONDecoder()
let newUserResponse = try? jsondecode.decode(NewUser.self, from: data!)
print(newUserResponse)
```

The **newUserResponse** print the nil but it should print some response. unable to find the issue.

Comment: The "message" response looks interesting. why no quotes on the String ? "Record Sucessfully Inserted."  Also , the response is an Array not a dictionary. Is that really the response data?

Comment: Yeah that look wrong. but got the issue it was firstName should be as string not as int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at firstName. (That's the answer by the way).

And for debugging, print the originial JSON data, not the result of something processing it. What you claim is the response of the API is not valid JSON whatsoever.

And using ".allowFragments" indicates that you have been blindly copying some code without understanding it. If you disagree then you may post what it does and why you are using it.

Comment: yeah I was copy the code. only for the testing purpose to run the code. Any way thanks for the response and pointing the issue...